# Why code in viewModelScope.launch ends after collect?

Tags: android, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have this lines of codes in a viewModel class:

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d(TAG, "fetchEsayosFromAT: in viewModelScope.launch")

        baseUrlFlow.collect {
            Log.d(TAG, "baseUrlFlow.collect fetchEsayosFromAT: baseUrl : $it")
            baseUrl = it
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "despues de collect fetchEsayosFromAT: baseUrl $baseUrl")
```

In logcat, I can see the first line of log.d in baseUrlFlow.collect, but never get the message after that . "despues...."

Why is that?
Best regards!

Comment: collecting on `baseUrlFlow` is probably a blocking call

Comment: Does the flow `baseUrlFlow` ever end?

Comment: `collect` is a suspend function, it's not blocking @MarkKeen; the thing is this flow probably never finishes that's why it's in the suspended state forever.

"Collect is a suspending function that suspends the calling coroutine while the flow is being collected" - [Source](https://elizarov.medium.com/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9)

Comment: @V1raNi Sure - I was alluding to saying that everything in the coroutine is sequential.  If the OP used a nested coroutine then the problem would be solved

Comment: @MarkKeen "blocking" in the context of Kotlin coroutines usually means "thread-blocking". You're not wrong, in that another definition of "blocking" is what you mean. But using words this way is not good for communication.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung I get what you are saying but if collecting on `baseUrlFlow` is a network call, for instance, and no dispatcher is used, then it won't have a chance to even "suspend" and will be "thread blocking" - causing all execution of the scope (and underlying thread) to block. Its more nuanced than just saying as its coroutines it suspends and is not thread blocking hence why I used the more general term "blocking" based on supplied code.

Answer (score -1):

That is the expected behavior. Take a look at this and run the example by pressing play button. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency